# Tkinter - How to ignore delete action in Text widget's undo system?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating Text Editor.
I implement set-text-content function and clear-text-content function.
That implementation is the following.

```
def clear(self):
    self.text_widget.delete(1.0, 'end')

def set_content(self, content):
    content = self.remove_unsupported_characters(content)
    self.clear()
    self.text_widget.insert(1.0, content)
```

That's functions is works fine. But Text widget's undo system recoding delete-action. So, my Text Editor's undo is not smooth.
So I want to ignore `self.text_widget.delete(1.0, 'end')` in undo system. How to do it?

Comment: You mean the default `undo`?

Comment: `undo` is `self.text_widget.edit_undo()` of `Text` widget. Current my Editor recoding `delete` action so undo history is not smooth (contains blank contents). And I need Ctrl+Z.

Comment: Well I can't find anything useful but you can try turning off `autoseparators` but you will have to call `edit_undo` every time the presses space bar/backspace.

Comment: Thank you. I try. That feeling is close.

Comment: FWIW, `1.0` isn't a valid index. Text widget indexes are strings, not floating point numbers. This works as a quirk of how the widget is implemented, but a floating point index like `1.10` won't work the way you expect.

Comment: @CoolCloud: Text widget indexes are strings of the form _line.char_. So, for example, `"1.10"` refers to the 10th character on the first line. The floating-point number `1.10` is the same as the number `1.1`. When Tkinter converts `1.10` to a string you end up with `"1.1"` which is a different index from `"1.10"`. In other words, the floating-point numbers `1.1`, `1.10`, and `1.100` all resolve to the same character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that if you turn off the `autoseparator` just before the deletion/insertion of text and turn it on again after it does the trick:

```py
import tkinter as tk

def stop_separators():
    text.edit_separator()
    text.config(autoseparator=False)

def start_separators():
    text.config(autoseparator=True)
    text.edit_separator()

def backspace(event):
    # turn off tkinter's autoseparators
    stop_separators()
    # let's remove 4 characters
    text.delete("insert-4c", "insert")
    # and insert Hi to replace them
    text.insert("insert", "Hi")
    # turn on tkinter's autoseparators
    start_separators()
    return "break"

root = tk.Tk()

text = tk.Text(root, undo=True)
text.pack()

text.bind("<BackSpace>", backspace)
text.insert("0.0", "aaaaa")

root.mainloop()
```

To try out the code press backspace and undo.